# Какого рода слово "брюки-юбка"?

Tags: морфология

Есть такой предмет одежды брюки-юбка. Только вот это *они* или *она*? Какое слово тут является определяющим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то этот предмет одежды называется, кажется, юбка-брюки. Но сути это не меняет, поскольку имеем дело со сложным существительным, образованным способом сложения. Ведущим компонентом является слово, выражающее более широкое понятие или конкретно обозначающее предмет, например: ***диван**-кровать **куплен** по старой цене, **платье**-костюм **сшито** по новой модели, **машина**-фургон **должна** использоваться по назначению*. Как правило, это первая часть слов, образованных по такой модели.

Если вы настаиваете на *брюках-юбке*, то вам, видимо, важнее, что это брюки (слово множ. числа, формы ед.числа нет, род у таких сущ. обычно не определяют, но склоняется оно по типу слов женского рода). Значит, согласовываться другие члены предложения будут именно с частью **брюки**: джинсовые брюки-юбка, брюки-юбка висят в шкафу и пр.

Мне же нравится **юбка-брюки** (слово юбка - женского рода). Кстати, именно этот вид одежды упомянут в Терминологическом словаре одежды Орленко Л.В.: "*Юбка-брюки - вид поясной одежды; появилась около 1830 г. как часть спортивной одежды. **Брючный покрой Ю.-Б. заметен только при ходьбе, т.к. скрывается глубокими складками**. Такая одежда удобна для отдыха, для занятия туризмом. Современные Ю.-Б. шьют как для каждого дня, так и в качестве выходной молодежной одежды.*"